# Is there a spider for Zend Lucene?

Tags: zend-framework, web-crawler

Is there a pre-written PHP spider/crawler that can be used to feed documents to the Zend_Search_Lucene indexer? I've found [Sphider](http://www.sphider.eu/) but it is very tightly coupled to MySQL, and not able to be integrated easily with Zend Lucene (as far as I can tell)

I'd originally written the search index to work on CMS/Wordpress page-save, so no spidering was needed, but now we need to integrate an external site too.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Spizer](http://github.com/shevron/spizer), it is currenty using Zend_Console to run form CLI so I think it shouldn't be hard to implement your own logger that is using Zend_Search_Lucene.